# Getting data in Console but cant All display in ionic 5 angular

Tags: api, ionic5, angular11

I'm using ionic 5 and angular 11 for front-end and for back-end laravel api crud,
for my back-end it works good
I could not get any error in this problem I cant display data in page but I get it in console

this is my page **annonce.ts****

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnnonceService } from '../annonce.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-annonce',
templateUrl: './annonce.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./annonce.page.scss'],
})
export class AnnoncePage implements OnInit {
productData:any;  


constructor(
  private service:AnnonceService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {}
ionViewWillEnter(){
this.getAllProduct()
}
getAllProduct(){
  this.service.getAllProduct().subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res)
    this.productData=res
    this.productData = Array.of(this.productData); 

  })
}
deleteProduct(id){
  this.service.deleteProduct(id).subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res)
            this.productData=res

    //mise a jour d'annonce
    this.getAllProduct()
    
  })
}
}
```

and this is **annonce.service.ts**

```
getAllProduct():  Observable<Product>{
return this.http.get<Product>(this.api_URL).pipe(retry(2), catchError(this.handleError)) }
```

and this is **annonce.html**

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of productData">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label> 
      <h2>{{item.title}}</h2> 
      <h2>{{item.descripton}}</h2> 
      <p>{{item.price}}</p> 
    </ion-label>
    <ion-note slot="end">
      detailleProduct
    </ion-note>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item-options>
    <!--edit-->
    <ion-item-option>
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create" [routerLink]="['/','edit-annonce', item.id]"> </ion-icon>
    </ion-item-option>
    <!--delete-->
    <ion-item-option color="danger"> 
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash" (click)="deleteProduct(item.id)"> </ion-icon>
    </ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

[image of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDCA8.png)

Comment: please add response data so i check with example

Comment: what do you mean ? where I add it ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `this.productData` is not properly handled. In your response you get this data which you logged to the console and assign to `this.productData`:

```
{
  data: [{...}] some array,
  links: {...},
  meta: {...}
} // response object
```

In the next line `this.productData = Array.of(this.productData);` you assign this to `this.productData` (remark the `[]`):

```
 [{
  data: [{...}],
  links: {...},
  meta: {...}
 }] 
// array of responses
```

You probably want to do this to get your data out of the response

```
this.productData = res.data;
```